# Allowing custom tags in TinyMCE for integration with indexhibit

Tags: javascript, tinymce, editor, rich-text-editor, indexhibit

I'm trying to allow some custom tags to be entered into TinyMCE. The tag is

```
<plug:plugin_name />
```

However this is turned into

```
<plug:plugin_name></plug:plugin_name>
```

I'm about to write a regex to deal with this as I have to get the job done, I'd really rather not, but it will fix my issue.

I've tried many of the init options:

```
extended_valid_elements : "plug.plugin_name[*]",
custom_elements: "plug.plugin_name[*]",
verify_html : false, **//This ment that the tag wasn't ouright removed**
selfclosetags : \" />\", //some plugin I found, didn't seem to work
closed : /^(br|hr|input|meta|img|link|param|area|plug:plugin_name)$/,
```

Anyone else definitely got this to work with a recent version of TinyMCE?

**Also, another problem will be the editor will strip away the  tag, after I have fixed it with the regex!**

Comment: 3.4.2 Another problem is when the editor first loads, it will remove the <plug:plugin_name /> tag as well!

Comment: hmm, as far as i know the check for valid elements (the algorithm) has changed from version 3.9.x to 3.4.x . Why do you use 3.4.x? this version is still beta. I will switch to 3.4.x if it is stable enough.

Comment: What kind of information is it that you need to save? Can it be done without markup or perhaps with another element?

Comment: It is to use the editor with Indexhibit, and it uses a custom tag. Will probably not be an issue in the next version of Indexhibit.

Comment: Does TinyMCE handle `<br/>` and `<img/>` properly? I can't tell if the `closed:` part is part of that "plugin [you] found" or if it is part of TinyMCE.

Comment: Or is it simply because you did `plug.plugin_name` instead of `plug:plugin_name` per [this reference](http://topsecretproject.finitestatemachine.com/2010/02/how-to-custom-tags-with-tinymce/).

Comment: @ChrisBarry Just saying there's a typo on line 3 in your third code example. The "**" produces a syntax error.

Same code on line 5 you add the option "plug:plugin_name" which only matches that string. You need "plug:(some regex that matches valid variable names)".

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add it to the list of short ended elements:

```
extended_valid_elements : "plug:plugin_name[*]",
custom_elements: "~plug:plugin_name[*]",
short_ended_elements: 'area base basefont br col frame hr img input isindex link meta param embed source wbr track plug:plugin_name'
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xp0xx1k/1/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
closed : /^(br|hr|input|meta|img|link|param|area|plug:plugin_name)$/,
```

Does this work?

```
closed : /^(br|hr|input|meta|img|link|param|area|plug)$/,
```

Note the last item "plug" without the : modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this option?

```
valid_elements: "a,br,span,plug:plugin_name,another:tag"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use encoding method as raw for any type of data.

```
tinyMCE.init({
   encoding : "raw"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First lets create a custom plugin for your Tinymce 4 editor.and then add a menu item for this plugin:

   ```
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('YOUR_CUSTOM_PLUGIN_NAME_HERE', function(editor, url){
              //add first menu item
       editor.addMenuItem('YOUR_MENU_ITEM1_CUSTOM_NAME_HERE', {

       text: 'Menu Item 1',
       context: 'YOUR_CUSTOM_DROP_DOWN_MENU_NAME', 
       onclick: function() {
          //make the magic happen when the user click this menu here...
       } });
   ```

   you are done creating your custom plugin and custom menu items, lets actually add it to the Tinymce 4 editor. This will be done in the tinymce.init method:

   ```
   tinymce.init({
           selector: "textarea",
           plugins: "YOUR_CUSTOM_PLUGIN_NAME_HERE",
           toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",

       //this is how you will get your custom menu like in the above image
               menu : {
                    YOUR_CUSTOM_DROP_DOWN_MENU_NAME: {

                        title: 'Name it whatever you like here',
                        items: 'YOUR_MENU_ITEM1_CUSTOM_NAME_HERE YOUR_MENU_ITEM2_CUSTOM_NAME_HERE YOUR_MENU_ITEM3_CUSTOM_NAME_HERE'
                    }
                },

                menubar: 'YOUR_CUSTOM_DROP_DOWN_MENU_NAME' 
       });

       });
   ```